# Get X position of a character inside Layout

Tags: android

TLDR, want to get the X position of a character inside a layout. Tried `getPrimaryHorizontal` and it does what I need, but need to create a Static/Dynamic layout for each view. This might bring perf issues. Was wondering if there is another way, where I can update the text I want to take measurements from.

Additional context

Building a "Custom BackgroundColorSpan" because of design requirements. Wanted to optimize and not create a Layout for each instance it might measure.
First I tried to "Calculate" where the text might be but found edge cases like LTR/RTL text on same line.